# Python to run Linux commands

Tags: python, linux, command

**I want to execute few linux commands using  python
these are my commands.**

```
modprobe ipv6
ip tunnel add he-ipv6 mode sit remote 216.218.221.6 local 117.211.75.3 ttl 255
ip link set he-ipv6 up
ip addr add 2001:470:18:f3::2/64 dev he-ipv6
ip route add ::/0 dev he-ipv6
ip -f inet6 addr
```

**216.218.221.6 

117.211.75.3 

2001:470:18:f3::2/64**

**these ip's are the inputs from the user. Commands also need root privileges.
My Code upto now.**

```
import os

print("Enter Server Ipv4 Address")
serverip4=input()

print("Enter Local Ipv4 Address")
localip4=input()

print("Enter Client Ipv6 Address")
clientip4=input()
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you believe that Python is better suited for this than a shell script?

Comment: I am Learning Python .. So, just .. Trying things :)..

Comment: You should look into the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module.

Comment: I am doing . But i am not getting how to add user input.

Answer (score 3):

I guess, subprocess would be best choice in this scenario as you want to get all command results and use it.
You can refer this page for that: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Here is the code:

```
import subprocess

#To use the sudo -> echo "password" | sudo <command>

ipv6_command_list = "echo 'password' | sudo 'ip tunnel add he-ipv6 mode sit remote 216.218.221.6 local 117.211.75.3 ttl 255'"
ip_link_list = "echo 'password' | sudo 'ip link set he-ipv6 up'"
ip_addr_list = "echo 'password' | sudo 'ip addr add 2001:470:18:f3::2/64 dev he-ipv6'"
ip_route_list = "echo 'password' |sudo 'ip route add ::/0 dev he-ipv6'"
ip_inet_list = "echo 'password' | sudo 'ip -f inet6 addr'"

for ip_command in [ip_link_list,ip_addr_list,ip_route_list,ip_inet_list]:
    proc = subprocess.check_output(ip_command, shell=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
import sys
import os
os.system("ip tunnel add he-ipv6 mode sit remote %s local %s ttl 255" % (whicheveripvariableisfirst), (whicheveripvariableisnext)))
```

If you need it run at sudo level then put sudo in the command section or make sure to run the python script as sudo.